# mod_wsgi with dynamically allocated UIDs

Tags: apache-2.2, unix, mod-wsgi, users, uid

I have a system where users upload wsgi applications and we serve them using apache/mod_wsgi.  For scaling reasons, we're simply using the WSGIDaemonProcess directive and setting them to dynamically allocated UID/GIDs.  The problem is, we don't have associated users with these UIDs.

Is there a way to keep mod_wsgi from trying to determine the "user" associated with a particular UID?  I can't find a directive anywhere that does this.

EDIT: Taking a look at the mod_wsgi.c source, it appears (near line 9700) that the conditional check for an entry in /etc/passwd is hard-coded.

In other words, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussion about this on mod_wsgi mailing list at:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_frm/thread/193c15873ccba18c